# Multiple instances of /usr/sbin/ifplugd and high CPU usage

Tags: raspbian, cpu, networking, ppp

why do i have multiple instances of /usr/sbin/ifplugd running, is there a problem
Also my CPU seem to be running Maxed

PPP0 is the 3g card. and currently it is connected

```
07:56:38 up  7:57,  1 user,  load average: 4.03, 4.16, 4.14
```

here is also a print out of /etc/default/ifplugd

```
INTERFACES="auto"
HOTPLUG_INTERFACES="all"
ARGS="-q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I"
SUSPEND_ACTION="stop"
```

here is a printout of ps aux, please note the high CPU consumption by udevd --daemon

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.5  0.0   2144    76 ?        Ss   Dec02   2:39 init [2]
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   0:15 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [kworker/u:0H]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [khelper]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [netns]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   0:00 [bdi-default]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [kblockd]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   0:00 [khubd]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [rpciod]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        17  0.5  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   2:31 [kswapd0]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [nfsiod]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [crypto]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:02 [VCHIQ-0]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [VCHIQr-0]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [VCHIQs-0]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [iscsi_eh]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [dwc_otg]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [DWC Notificatio]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [deferwq]
root        37  1.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   5:03 [mmcqd/0]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   0:06 [jbd2/mmcblk0p2-]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       154 23.0 13.7  45140 42688 ?        Rs   Dec02 108:32 udevd --daemon
root       220  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec02   0:00 [bcm2708_spi.0]
root       287  1.5  0.1   2896   432 ?        S    Dec02   7:10 udevd --daemon
root       291  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   0:05 [flush-179:0]
root       292  1.2  0.1   2896   440 ?        S    Dec02   6:05 udevd --daemon
root       314  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:18   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root       600  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   0:00 [scsi_eh_3]
root       601  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec02   0:00 [usb-storage]
root       660  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:19   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root       679  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:19   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      1467  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:20   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      1635  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    Dec02   0:27 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i eth0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      1653  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    Dec02   0:09 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i lo -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      1683  3.8  0.0   3344   152 ?        S    Dec02  17:54 /usr/sbin/pppd call pptpconf
root      1906  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:43   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      1982  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:21   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      2868  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:08   0:04 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      2878  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:08   0:04 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      2915  4.3  1.0  31168  3300 ?        Sl   00:00  20:38 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
root      3285  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:22   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      3317  0.0  2.9  39068  9064 ?        Ss   00:00   0:10 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      3318  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:22   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      3466  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:43   0:06 [kworker/u:0]
root      3489  0.0  0.0   3824   196 ?        Ss   00:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
root      3570  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:22   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      3574  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:22   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      3576  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:22   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
104       3639  0.0  0.0   3176     4 ?        Ss   00:00   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
avahi     3738  0.7  0.2   3488   684 ?        S    00:00   3:36 avahi-daemon: running [prayertime.local]
avahi     3744  0.0  0.0   3380     4 ?        S    00:00   0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
root      4285  0.0  1.4  11592  4428 ?        S    00:00   0:21 ddclient - sleeping for 100 seconds
root      4419  0.0  0.1   2376   320 ?        Ss   00:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/dropbear -d /etc/dropbear/dropbear_dss_host_key -r /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key -p 22 -W 65536
root      4538  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:58   0:05 [kworker/u:1]
root      4624  0.0  0.0   1756     4 ?        S    00:00   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
root      4848  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:36   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      4853  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:36   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      4925  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:27   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      5691  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:26   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
mysql     5761  0.8  0.5 315832  1708 ?        Sl   00:00   4:02 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysql
root      5762  0.0  0.0   1848     4 ?        S    00:00   0:00 logger -t mysqld -p daemon.error
root      6201  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:27   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      6374  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:27   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      6375  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:27   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      6626  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:28   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      6631  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:28   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
ntp       6749  0.2  0.1   5592   472 ?        Ss   00:01   1:20 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 102:104
root      6837  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:28   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      6978  0.0  0.0   9656   220 ?        Ss   00:01   0:08 /usr/sbin/nmbd -D
root      7024  0.0  0.3  18868  1168 ?        Ss   00:01   0:01 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
root      7052  0.0  0.0  19384     4 ?        S    00:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
nobody    7264  0.0  0.0   2016    36 ?        Ss   00:01   0:01 /usr/sbin/thd --daemon --triggers /etc/triggerhappy/triggers.d/ --socket /var/run/thd.socket --pidfile /var/run/thd.pid --user nobody /de
root      7296  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:28   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      7311  0.0  0.0   5008     4 ?        S    00:01   0:00 udevd --daemon
root      7313  0.0  0.0   3744     4 tty1     Ss+  00:01   0:00 /sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1
root      7314  0.0  0.0   3744     4 tty2     Ss+  00:01   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty2
root      7315  0.0  0.0   3744     4 tty3     Ss+  00:01   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty3
root      7316  0.0  0.0   3744     4 tty4     Ss+  00:01   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty4
root      7317  0.0  0.0   3744     4 tty5     Ss+  00:01   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty5
root      7318  0.0  0.0   3744     4 tty6     Ss+  00:01   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty6
root      8430  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    00:01   0:00 [VCHIQka-0]
root      9238  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:59   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
www-data  9920  0.0  1.5  39092  4736 ?        S    06:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9921  0.0  1.5  39092  4716 ?        S    06:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9923  0.0  1.5  39092  4716 ?        S    06:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9927  0.0  1.5  39092  4716 ?        S    06:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9928  0.0  1.5  39092  4716 ?        S    06:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     10153  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:37   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     10155  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:37   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     10166  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:37   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     11142  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:47   0:00 [kworker/0:2]
root     11431  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:29   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     12491  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:38   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     12522  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:38   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     12752  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    02:29   0:06 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     13344  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:01   0:05 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     13565  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:30   0:04 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     13566  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:30   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     13895  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    02:07   0:08 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     16546  0.4  0.0   9088   308 ?        S    04:01   1:05 /usr/bin/wvdial
root     16571  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:12   0:04 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     16577  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:12   0:04 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     16786  0.0  0.0   3344   152 ?        S    04:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/pppd 57600 modem crtscts defaultroute usehostname -detach user notused noipdefault call wvdial usepeerdns idle 0 logfd 6
root     17220  0.0  0.0   1756     4 ?        S    04:01   0:00 sh -c pptp 123.243.74.68 --nolaunchpppd --debug
root     17486  0.0  0.1   1780   392 ?        S    04:01   0:02 pptp 123.243.74.68 --nolaunchpppd --debug
root     17577  0.0  0.0   1780   132 ?        S    04:01   0:00 pptp 123.243.74.68 --nolaunchpppd --debug
root     18022  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:19   0:02 [kworker/0:1]
root     18076  0.0  0.3   3040  1208 ?        Ss   06:38   0:02 /usr/sbin/dropbear -d /etc/dropbear/dropbear_dss_host_key -r /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key -p 22 -W 65536
root     18239  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:13   0:04 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     18862  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    02:42   0:06 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
pi       19104  0.0  0.3   2928  1004 pts/1    R+   07:49   0:00 ps aux
pi       19975  0.0  1.0   4768  3304 pts/1    Ss   06:39   0:01 -bash
root     20368  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:31   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     21076  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:04   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     21135  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    02:53   0:05 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     22245  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   01:36   0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
root     24882  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:09   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     25932  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:41   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     26937  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:11   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     26969  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:11   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     28737  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:13   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     30122  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:14   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     30647  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:57   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     30776  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:15   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     31377  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:16   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     31519  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:16   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     31523  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:16   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     31719  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:34   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     31880  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:17   0:03 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     31886  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:17   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     32112  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    03:57   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root     32634  0.0  0.0   1748    48 ?        S    04:18   0:02 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i ppp0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
```

here is a copy of /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp


auto ppp0
iface ppp0 inet wvdial

auto tunnel
iface tunnel inet ppp
provider pptpconf
```

also

```
$ ./ifplugstatus
ppp0: link beat detected
ppp1: link beat detected
lo: link beat detected
eth0: unplugged
```

Answer (score 1):

> why do i have multiple instances of /usr/sbin/ifplugd running, is there a problem

I normally have `ifplugd` disabled but this does seem wrong.  It *might* also be the cause the cause of `udevd` revving up.  You could test this:

```
> sudo service ifplugd stop
> sudo killall ifplugd
> ps -C ifplugd
```

The last one is to double check.  It should show no processes.

If that works, you can permanently disable `ifplugd`:

```
sudo update-rc.d ifplugd disable S 2 3 4 5
```

The purpose of `ifplugd` is really to deal with the ethernet jack, so you could also just try configuring it to only do that (there could be some sort of circular interaction with udev regarding the 3G dongle).  `udev` is a (completely separate) kernel interface that responds to hardware interrupts triggered by adding and removing various devices.  Plugging in an ethernet cable doesn't do this.  On normal linux systems, if a link is available at boot, a connection is arranged then.  However, plugging in a cable later won't do anything.  This is a PITA with a headless device like the pi, hence `ifplugd`, an independent userland service, is available.

Plugging in USB devices definitely does trigger the kernel, so you should probably just use udev for that, not ifplugd.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the mail problem. But would disabling it disable the reconnection of the 3g when connection is list or add well the Ethernet

Comment: You could add a rule directly to udev WRT the 3G dongle.  The reason for `ifplugd` is I believe primarily for the ethernet jack; plugging this in doesn't trigger anything with udev so ifplugd is there to watch for it.  It's not used w/ normal linux systems, where `NetworkManager` is used to arrange connections at boot, but hotplugging an ethernet cable doesn't do anything.  This is awkward with a headless device like the pi.  You should be able to find some tutorial about creating a udev rule online, but you're welcome to ask a specific question about that if you want.

Comment: I've added a couple of paragraphs about ifplugd vs. udev above.